# Is there a reason that we cannot iterate on "reverse Range" in ruby?

Tags: ruby, iteration, range

I tried to iterate backwards with using a Range and `each`:

```
(4..0).each do |i|
  puts i
end
==> 4..0
```

Iteration through `0..4` writes the numbers. On the other Range `r = 4..0` seems to be ok, `r.first == 4`, `r.last == 0`.

It seems to be strange to me that the construct above does not produce the expected result. What is the a reason for that? What are the situations when this behaviour is reasonable?

Comment: I am not only interested in how to realise this iteration, which is obviously not supported, but rather why does it return the range 4..0 itself. What was the intention of the language designers? Why, in which situations is it good? I saw similar behaviour in other ruby constructs as well, and it is still not clean when it is useful.

Comment: The range itself is returned by convention.  Since the `.each` statement didn't modify anything, there is no computed "result" to return.  When this is the case, Ruby typically returns the original object on success and `nil` on error.  This lets you use expressions like this as conditions on an `if` statement.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

A range is just that: something defined by its start and end, not by its contents. "Iterating" over a range doesn't really make sense in a general case. Consider, for example, how you would "iterate" over the range produced by two dates. Would you iterate by day? by month? by year? by week? It's not well-defined. IMO, the fact that it's allowed for forward ranges should be viewed as a convenience method only.

If you want to iterate backwards over a range like that, you can always use `downto`:

```
$ r = 10..6
=> 10..6

$ (r.first).downto(r.last).each { |i| puts i }
10
9
8
7
6
```

Here are [**some more thoughts**](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/110660#255691) from others on why it's tough to both allow iteration and consistently deal with reverse-ranges.

Comment: I think iterating over a range from 1 to 100 or from 100 to 1 intuitively means using step 1. If someone wants a different step, changes the default. Similarly, for me (at least) iterating from 1st of January to 16th of August means stepping by days. I think there is often something we can commonly agree on, because we intuitively mean it that way.
Thanks for your answer, also the link you gave was useful.

Comment: I still think defining "intuitive" iterations for many ranges is challenging to do consistently, and I don't agree that iterating over dates that way intuitively implies a step equal to 1 day -- after all, a day itself is already a range of time (from midnight to midnight). For example, who's to say that "January 1 to August 18" (exactly 20 weeks) doesn't imply an iteration of weeks instead of days? Why not iterate by hour, minute, or second?

Comment: The `.each` there is redundant, `5.downto(1) { |n| puts n }` works fine. Also, instead of all that r.first r.last stuff, just do `(6..10).reverse_each`.

Comment: @Mk12: 100% agree, I was just trying to be super-explicit for the sake of newer Rubyists. Maybe that's too confusing, though.

Comment: When trying to add years to a form, I used: `= f.select :model_year, (Time.zone.now.year + 1).downto(Time.zone.now.year - 100).to_a`

Comment: `reverse_each` does not build a temporary array starting from Ruby 3.3

https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.3.html#reverse_each

Answer (score 108):

How about `(0..1).reverse_each` which iterates the range backwards?

Comment: It builds temporary array, at least in 2.4.1 https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each

Comment: This worked for me sorting a range of dates `(Date.today.beginning_of_year..Date.today.yesterday).reverse_each` Thanks

Comment: `reverse_each` does not build a temporary array starting from Ruby 3.3

https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.3.html#reverse_each

Answer (score 19):

Iterating over a range in Ruby with `each` calls the `succ` method on the first object in the range.

```
$ 4.succ
=> 5
```

And 5 is outside the range.

You can simulate reverse iteration with this hack:

```
(-4..0).each { |n| puts n.abs }
```

John pointed out that this will not work if it spans 0. This would:

```
>> (-2..2).each { |n| puts -n }
2
1
0
-1
-2
=> -2..2
```

Can't say I really like any of them because they kind of obscure the intent.

Comment: No but by multiplying by -1 instead of using .abs you can.

Answer (score 16):

Another way is `(1..10).to_a.reverse`

Comment: Worth noting this `(10..1).to_a.reverse` does not work.

Answer (score 12):

According to the book "Programming Ruby", the Range object stores the two endpoints of the range and uses the `.succ` member to generate the intermediate values.  Depending on what kind of data type you are using in your range, you can always create a subclass of `Integer` and re-define the `.succ` member so that it acts like a reverse iterator (you would probably also want to re-define `.next` as well).

You can also achieve the results you are looking for without using a Range.  Try this:

```
4.step(0, -1) do |i|
    puts i
end
```

This will step from 4 to 0 in steps of -1.  However, I don't know if this will work for anything except Integer arguments.

Answer (score 9):

You can even use a `for` loop:

```
for n in 4.downto(0) do
  print n
end
```

which prints:

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 4):

if list is not that big.
i think
`[*0..4].reverse.each { |i| puts i }` 
is simplest way.

Comment: IMO it is generally good to assume it is big. I think it is the right belief and habit to follow generally. And as the devil never sleeps, I do not trust myself that I remember where I iterated over an array.
But you are right, if we have 0 and 4 constant, iterating over array might not cause any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I add one another possibility how to realise iteration over reverse Range. I do not use it, but it is a possibility. It is a bit risky to monkey patch ruby core objects.

```
class Range

  def each(&block)
    direction = (first<=last ? 1 : -1)
    i = first
    not_reached_the_end = if first<=last
                            lambda {|i| i<=last}
                          else
                            lambda {|i| i>=last}
                          end
    while not_reached_the_end.call(i)
      yield i
      i += direction
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As bta said, the reason is that `Range#each` sends `succ` to its beginning, then to the result of that `succ` call, and so on until the result is greater than the end value. You can't get from 4 to 0 by calling `succ`, and in fact you already start out greater than the end.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote

> It seems to be strange to me that the construct above does not produce
>   the expected result. What is the a reason for that? What are the
>   situations when this behaviour is reasonable?

not 'Can it be done?' but to answer the question that wasn't asked before getting to the question that was actually asked:

```
$ irb
2.1.5 :001 > (0..4)
 => 0..4
2.1.5 :002 > (0..4).each { |i| puts i }
0
1
2
3
4
 => 0..4
2.1.5 :003 > (4..0).each { |i| puts i }
 => 4..0
2.1.5 :007 > (0..4).reverse_each { |i| puts i }
4
3
2
1
0
 => 0..4
2.1.5 :009 > 4.downto(0).each { |i| puts i }
4
3
2
1
0
 => 4
```

Since reverse_each is claimed to build an entire array, downto is clearly going to be more efficient. The fact that a language designer could even consider implementing things like that kinda ties into the answer to the actual question as asked.

To answer the question as actually asked...

The reason is because Ruby is an endlessly surprising language. Some surprises are pleasant, but there is a lot of behaviour which is downright broken. Even if some of these following examples are corrected by newer releases, there are plenty of others, and they remain as indictments on the mindset of the original design:

```
nil.to_s
   .to_s
   .inspect
```

results in "" but

```
nil.to_s
#  .to_s   # Don't want this one for now
   .inspect
```

results in

```
 syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting end-of-input
 .inspect
 ^
```

You would probably expect << and push to be the same for appending to arrays, but

```
a = []
a << *[:A, :B]    # is illegal but
a.push *[:A, :B]  # isn't.
```

You would probably expect 'grep' to behave like its Unix command-line equivalent, but it does === matching not =~, despite its name.

```
$ echo foo | grep .
foo
$ ruby -le 'p ["foo"].grep(".")'
[]
```

Various methods are unexpectedly aliases for each other, so you have to learn multiple names for the same thing - e.g. `find` and `detect` - even if you do like most developers and only ever use one or the other. Much the same goes for `size`, `count`, and `length`, except for classes which define each differently, or don't define one or two at all.

Unless someone has implemented something else - like the core method `tap` has been redefined in various automation libraries to press something on the screen. Good luck finding out what's going on, especially if some module required by some other module has monkeyed yet another module to do something undocumented.

The environment variable object, ENV does not support 'merge', so you have to write

```
 ENV.to_h.merge('a': '1')
```

As a bonus, you can even redefine your or someone else's constants if you change your mind about what they should be.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way, shape, or form. It is nothing but a rant about things the author doesn't like about Ruby.

Comment: Updated to answer the question that isn't asked, in addition to the answer that was actually asked. *rant: verb 1. speak or shout at length in an angry, impassioned way.* The original answer wasn't angry or impassioned: it was a considered response with examples.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The original question also includes: *It seems to be strange to me that the construct above does not produce the expected result. What is the a reason for that? What are the situations when this behaviour is reasonable?* so he's after reasons, not code solutions.

Comment: Again, I fail to see how the behavior of `grep` is in any way, shape or form related to the fact that iterating over an empty range is a no-op. Nor do I see how the fact that iterating over an empty range is a no-op is in any way shape or form "endlessly surprising" and "downright broken".

Comment: Because a range 4..0 has the obvious intention of [4, 3, 2, 1, 0] but surprisingly doesn't even raise a warning. It surprised the OP and it surprised me, and has doubtlessly surprised many other people. I listed other examples of surprising behaviour. I can cite more, if you like. Once something exhibits more than a certain amount of surprising behaviour, it starts to drift into the territory of 'broken'. A bit like how constants raise a warning when overwritten, especially when methods don't.

Comment: This is such a good answer. Thoroughly enjoyed it. It seems I'm the first to upvote it, which is surprising!

Comment: Love all these examples of how Ruby is strange. Love the language, but it can be a pain. I've been bitten by this reverse range thing twice now (numbers in my input could be in ascending or descending order). I was so upset at the time I had wasted that I googled this behaviour and found this. It makes no sense! If a language construct is invalid, throw an error!

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, but today I found the following approach (which was not mentioned before):

```
(4..0).step(-1).each {|x| puts x}
```

Using an explicit step allows ruby to "know" how to proceed to the next value (instead of using the default `succ`).

The advantage of this approach is that no complete array has to be instantiated first, and it still is pretty readable/compact imho.

Answer (score 0):

As for me the simplest way is:

```
[*0..9].reverse
```

Another way to iterate for enumeration:

```
(1..3).reverse_each{|v| p v}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for my lazy use case

```
(-999999..0).lazy.map{|x| -x}.first(3)
#=> [999999, 999998, 999997]
```