# Why doesn't backward for loop work in ruby? eg. for i in 10..1

Tags: ruby, range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a reason that we cannot iterate on “reverse Range” in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070574/is-there-a-reason-that-we-cannot-iterate-on-reverse-range-in-ruby)

This works like magic.

```
for i in 1..10
  ...
end
```

Isn't it only intuitive that this backward for loop should work as well?

```
for i in 10..1
  ...
end
```

If there is some syntactical reason why this shouldn't work, I feel like ruby has to be changed to allow it. It's just intuitive to write backward for loop that way.

Comment: Are you looking for actual workarounds or reasons why it doesn't work?

Comment: Just wondering why it doesn't work. I am aware of other alternatives.

Comment: @closevoters: Fair enough newbie question. I expected `10..1` to work when I started programming Ruby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`1..10` is of class Range, not directly linked with any loop constructs. And there are no numbers that are both bigger than 10 and smaller than 1, therefore the range `10..1` is empty.

PS I don't recall when was the last time I wrote a for loop in ruby. Maybe something from http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html would serve you better?

Comment: Thank you. While I work with Rails, I never had to come across using for nor while. I just wanted to try writing different sorting methods with Ruby, and spent some time trying to figure out where I went wrong. Turns out I couldn't do backward for loop that way.

Answer (score 12):

try something like

```
10.downto(1) { |i| ... }
```