# How can I convert a step-down range to array?

Tags: ruby

I have a range like `(1000..0)` and I was using `each` but it does not do anything. I was trying to convert it to an array and got an empty array.

I also tried `(1000..0).step(-1).each` and it tells me `step cant be negative`...

Is there any way to use `(1000..0).each` so it will do the repetition, or convert to an array like `[1000,999,998,...,0]`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070574/is-there-a-reason-that-we-cannot-iterate-on-reverse-range-in-ruby => a lot of work arounds here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1000.downto(0).each { |i| ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

`(0..1000).to_a.reverse`
This will create the required array.

Comment: I can't say I've ever seen `map { |x| x }` before. Why would you do a no-op map?

Comment: Yeah, no idea how standard this is... I'm using a map to create an array. Converting the range to an array was one of the options given. Was just addressing that.

Comment: Any Range has a `to_a` method that does this a lot more elegantly.

Comment: Changed answer as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you might go about doing this:

```
(0..1000).each do |i|
  n = 1000 - i
  # Use n for all calculations
end

(0..1000).to_a.reverse.each do |n|
  # Involves creating temporary array, but overhead is usually minor for
  # relatively small numbers.
end
```

Don't forget you can also do this without a range:

```
1001.times do |i|
  n = 1000 - i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#1000 item array
step_down_array = 1000.step(0, -1).to_a

#small enumerator:
step_down = 1000.step(0, -1)
```