# How do I order a collection in decreasing order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

I am building a form to select a year from 2010 to current year.

```
= f.input :duration do
    = f.select :duration, options_for_select(2010..@currentyear.to_i)
```

and it gives me a drop down list:

[image: Dropdown]

But if I try to do it in descending order (like 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010),

```
options_for_select(@currentyear.to_i..2010)
```

I get a blank drop down menu. What do I do?

Comment: Descending order range is not supported in Ruby, you can try `(2010..@currentyear.to_i).to_a.reverse`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way to achieve this then? It's just that the user will find correct data in my application if he selects 2015, and so I want it on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
options_for_select(@currentyear.to_i..2010)
```

to

```
options_for_select((2010..@currentyear.to_i).to_a.reverse)
```

Comment: Yup! This worked! You are a genius.  So here I am just converting my range into an array and sorting it in reverse order

Answer (score 1):

Descending order range is not supported in Ruby, you can try `(2010..@currentyear.to_i).to_a.reverse`

Comment: undefined method `to_a' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x000000105149c8>

Comment: The above code snippet is valid ruby code that returns an array, please ensure you are placing it correctly in your code.  [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) accepts an array as input, hence, it should work.

Comment: Yeah it is correct. As spickermann specified in his answer, I was not enclosing that statement in parenthesis. Beginner's mistake. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user2839702 Its discouraging that correct and first given answer is not accepted.

Comment: yeah but Spickermann's answer told me exactly what to do.. got my code working.. so his was given the correct answer  If I could select two correct answers i would.. I am such a beginner that i cannot even upvote any answers!

Answer (score 1):

Reverse (integer) ranges are done with [downto](https://apidock.com/ruby/Integer/downto), so you can do

```
= f.input :duration do
    = f.select :duration, options_for_select(@currentyear.to_i.downto(2010))
```

Note, for the curious minds, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070587/797303) discusses why you can't iterate a range in reverse. The `downto` returns an Enumerator, not a Range, but both are Enumerable and work for the purpose of the original question.