# How do you reverse order in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you write a code snippet in Ruby that prints out, in reverse order, every multiple of 3 between 1 and 200?

This is the code I have so far:

```
(1..200).each do | i | ##loop it then
  if i % 3 == 0
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2070574/128421

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, @theTinMan. The linked question concerns descending ranges (e.g. `4..0`), which OP never mentions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want `#select` and `#reverse`.

```
puts (1..200).select { |i| i % 3 == 0 }.reverse
```

Comment: The OP merely wants to print the elements. It's not necessary to create an array to do that.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to print the multiples of three from 200 to 1 is using [`Integer#downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Integer.html#method-i-downto):

```
200.downto(1) do |i|
  puts i if i % 3 == 0
end
```

Unlike the other answers it does not require converting a range to an array or creating an array and reversing it.

Answer (score 1):

`Range` doesn't have a `#reverse` method, but you can call `#to_a` to return an array of those numbers, then call `#reverse_each` on that array to iterate over the numbers in reversed order:

```
(1..200).to_a.reverse_each { |i| puts i if i % 3 == 0 }
```

See the documentation on [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html) and [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html) for more information.

Comment: I suggest [`Array#reverse_each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each) instead of `reverse.each`.

Comment: Ruby never ceases to amaze me. Syntactic sugar that doesn't save a single character but still feels cleaner...

Comment: It's not syntactic sugar. It has different semantics. `reverse` initializes a second array (a duplicate of the first in reverse order), whereas `reverse_each` iterates over the original array from end to beginning.

Comment: `to_a` is unnecessary, and undesirable because it creates an unneeded temporary array.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
(1..200).to_a.reverse.each do |number|
  if number % 3 == 0
  puts number
  end
end
```

Here you're specifying a range of numbers from 1 to 200, converting them to an array, reversing the order and iterating through each element to see if it's divisible by 3 (i.e if you divide it by 3, it shouldn't have a remainder), then if so, printing the number :)

EDIT: as Jordan pointed out, writing

```
reverse_each
```

instead of

```
 reverse.each
```

is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wishes to print certain elements of a range. It is inefficient (but not necessary bad, of course) to first construct an array. My answer and some of the others do not create an array.

Suppose the range is of the form `first..last`. To print every `multiple` elements, in reverse order, you can write:

```
def rev_n_skip(first, last, multiple)
  (first..last).step(multiple).reverse_each { |i| print "#{i} " }
  puts
end

rev_n_skip(1, 19, 3) #-> 19 16 13 10 7 4 1 
rev_n_skip(1, 18, 3) #-> 16 13 10 7 4 1 
rev_n_skip(1, 17, 3) #-> 16 13 10 7 4 1 
rev_n_skip(1, 16, 3) #-> 16 13 10 7 4 1 
rev_n_skip(1, 15, 3) #-> 13 10 7 4 1 

rev_n_skip(2, 19, 3) #-> 17 14 11 8 5 2 
rev_n_skip(2, 18, 3) #-> 17 14 11 8 5 2 
rev_n_skip(2, 17, 3) #-> 17 14 11 8 5 2 
rev_n_skip(2, 16, 3) #-> 14 11 8 5 2 
rev_n_skip(2, 15, 3) #-> 14 11 8 5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign the value to the variable a then you can:

```
a.reverse!
puts a
```

This may also help as an example:

```
def reverse_string(string) # method reverse_string with parameter 'string'
  loop = string.length       # int loop is equal to the string's length
  word = ''                  # this is what we will use to output the reversed word
  while loop > 0             # while loop is greater than 0, subtract loop by 1 and add the string's index of loop to 'word'
    loop -= 1                  # subtract 1 from loop
    word += string[loop]       # add the index with the int loop to word
  end                        # end while loop
  return word                # return the reversed word
end                        # end the method
```

Answer (score 0):

Three other ways that don't require arrays are:

```
(1..200).reverse_each { |i| puts i if i % 3 == 0 }
```

Or:

```
(200..1).step(-1).each { |i| puts i if i % 3 == 0 }
```

And:

```
200.step(1, -1).each { |i| puts i if i % 3 == 0 }
```