# Ruby : Can you please explain why reverse range not giving expected result in ruby

Tags: ruby

why the below given `[]` for a reverse order range in ruby

```
(0..5).to_a
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(5..0).to_a
# => []
```

I am new on ruby PL

what is the best way to use a reverse range in ruby

The best way to use a reverse range for iteration

I know `.reverse` of array

But can I inherit the range and make a custom method of it and use it as a range

I also try

```
class Range
  def r
    to_a.reverse
  end
end
# => :r
(5..0).r
# => []
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a reason that we cannot iterate on "reverse Range" in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070574/is-there-a-reason-that-we-cannot-iterate-on-reverse-range-in-ruby)

Comment: what should I do if I need a reverse range

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

API doc explains how Ranges are created: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html

Comment: The concept of a reversed range brings to mind a tombstone that reads, "January 23, 2007 - July 8, 1938".

Comment: You really should wait awhile before selecting an answer. The point is that there is no rush to do so (just don't forget as long as there is at least one satisfactory answer). Many SOers wait at least a couple of hours, some much longer.

Comment: Sorry my bad...yes next time I will do that in a hurry to solve my prob at least a way I select it a least way at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked why `(5..0).to_a` doesn't give the "expected result", by which I assume you mean `[5,4,3,2,1]`.

If a range is `a..b` that means it includes all values `x` such that `a <= x <= b`.<sup>1</sup> If `a > b`, no values are included, so `nil` is returned. There is no such thing as an "empty" range, as there is an empty array (`[]`), hash (`{}`), string (`""`) and so on. (`1..1` is a range, but it is not empty.) That's why `5..3` cannot return a `Range` object, and therefore returns `nil`.

Ruby does not support the concept of a "reversed range". If you just want to step down from `3` to `1` there are many ways to do that without involving a range.

Note also that ranges, unlike arrays, for example, may contain an infinite number of values. `1.0..3.0` is one such example.

<sup>1 The range `a...b` (three dots) includes all values `x` such that `a <= x < b`.</sup>

Comment: perfect Sir ... you are best

Answer (score 2):

> what should I do if I need a reverse range

```
(0..5).to_a.reverse
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

or

```
(0..5).reverse_each.to_a
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: can I inherit the range and make it custom way not this one I expected

Comment: incase you want to use range, you can also use `reverse_each` enumerator on the range with (low .. high).

Comment: it is an enumerator and it is also work for array not range I try irb(main):010:0> (5..0).reverse_each do |i|
irb(main):011:1* puts i
irb(main):012:1> end
=> 5..0

Comment: yes I know. But I cannot understand whats the issue with that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it that might more closely express they way you're thinking about it:

```
(5.downto 0).to_a
=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
[*0..5].reverse
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

**OR**

```
> r = Proc.new {|x| x.reverse}
> r.call((0..5).to_a)
#=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```