# Positive to Negative range in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

I found out a function that reads a row of an excel sheet:

```
self.rows[start_row..-1]
```

where `start_row` is `12`.

I want to know the output of `print [12..-1]`. I tried these codes:

```
[12..-1].each{|n| puts n}
(12..-1).each {|n| puts n}
```

but found no luck. I get

```
[12..-1]
# [12..-1] 
[12..-1].each {|x| puts x}
# >> 12..-1
# => [12..-1] 
(12..-1).each {|x| puts x}
# => 12..-1
```

What is the range when it goes in negative direction from positive? How can I print such range in the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a reason that we cannot iterate on "reverse Range" in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070574/is-there-a-reason-that-we-cannot-iterate-on-reverse-range-in-ruby)

Comment: @Ilya , sorry but that didnt answer my question, the code I specified is currently working. The link that you have provided talks about the downward slope from positive to positive. But my question is from positive to negative.

Comment: The range which goes from 12 upwards to -1 is empty. There is nothing to iterate over. This is explained in three different answers to the question linked by Ilya.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the range when it goes in negative direction from positive?

I assume that `rows` is an array. In this case, `-1` denotes the *last element*, `-2` the penultimate, `-3` the antepenultimate, and so on:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

array[2..-1] #=> ["c", "d", "e", "f"]
array[2..-2] #=> ["c", "d", "e"]
array[2..-3] #=> ["c", "d"]
```

[`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) (among others) allows you to specify both, positive indices counting from the start and negative indices counting from the end:

```
# 0    1    2    3    4    5
#-6   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Implementation-wise, you can think of `array[-5]` as `array[array.length-5]`.

So both, `1` and `-5` reference `"b"`:

```
array[1]  #=> "b"
array[-5] #=> "b"
```

just like `4` and `-2` reference `"e"`:

```
array[4]  #=> "e"
array[-2] #=> "e"
```

and moreover, all of these ranges return the same subarray (for an array of length 6):

```
array[1..4]   #=> ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
array[1..-2]  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
array[-5..4]  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
array[-5..-2] #=> ["b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Your example:

```
rows[start_row..-1]
```

is equivalent to:

```
rows[start_row..rows.length-1]
```

---

To answer your other question

> How can I print such range in the console?

You can use [`downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-downto):

```
12.downto(-1) { |i| puts i }
```

Output:

```
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
-1
```

However, note that these are different indices than those returned by `rows[12..-1]`:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

array[3..-1]
#=> ["d", "e", "f"]

array.values_at(3, 2, 1, 0, -1)
#=> ["d", "c", "b", "a", "f"]
```

Answer (score 4):

[Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Range.html)s don't work going downward (either positive -> lesser positive, positive -> negative, or negative -> lesser negative) because:

> Methods that treat the range as a sequence (#each and methods inherited from Enumerable) expect the begin object to implement a succ method to return the next object in sequence.

and the [`Integer#succ`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-succ) method:

> Returns the successor of int, i.e. the Integer equal to int+1.

So you can't add one to a number and end up at a lesser number. The reason that `self.rows[start_row..-1]` works is because, while it's a `Range`, the [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) doesn't actually iterate through the range, and, the negative number at the `end` of the range isn't really treated as a negative number, but a *negative index* that tells the array to count backwards from the end of the array.

`Array#[]` actually ends up converting the Range into a `beginning index` and a `length` and returning `length` number of elements starting from `beg`.

---

As a sidenote, to print all numbers going from `12` -> `-1`, you can do

```
12.downto(-1) { |x| puts x }
```

but that isn't what the `Array#[]` method is doing, it treats the range as just a `begin` and an `end` and converted any negative numbers as counting backwards from the end of the array, with `-1` being the last element.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I print such range in the console?

If you want to use `range` and that in **positive** to **negative** order:

```
> (-1..12).to_a.reverse
#=> [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]
```

`range` in **negative** to **positive** order:

```
> (-1..12).to_a
#=> [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```